# C++ syntax for function that returns immutable vector of pointers

Tags: c++, vector, stl, constants

I have the following c++ function on MyClass:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    std::vector<MyObject*> getVector();
};
```

I want to make sure objects that grab this collection don't modify the collection or the contents. What is the appropriate c++ `const` usage to acheive this?

**Edit**: by "contents" I mean both the pointers and what they point to.

Comment: What is your definition of *content*? The pointers? The pointed objects? This makes all the difference

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Thanks for pointing that out. Question has been updated.

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for is the ability for the traverse this list, not actually return the list (a copy of it). Keeping around the list contained within a class seems like you are wanting to operate on that list both within a class, and have the callers able to operate on the list. Maybe it would help answer your question if you explained how the class and the caller(s) are supposed to interact with the list?

Comment: I've deleted my answer because I feel we're all running around in the dark. Why return a vector in the first place?

Comment: @larsmans:  I agree.  This whole thing smells bad.  Maybe the wrong question was asked in the first place.  Deleting as well.

Comment: Thanks for the input and patience with such a c++ beginner. I've asked the mods to delete the question as I'll ask a better one later.

Answer (score 4):

```
std::vector<const MyObject *> getVector();
```

or

```
const std::vector<const MyObject *> &getVector();
```

should do the trick.
You don't need the pointers to be constant, only the MyObject instances they are pointing to and the std::vector object (if returning a reference), so the vector won't alter its state and any referenced item won't be exposed as non-const.

Comment: The const on the return type is redundant if you don't return a reference. You cannot control whether the caller's copy is const.

Comment: The second version would require that there be a vector of const pointers stored somewhere (you can't just cast a vector of pointers to a vector of const pointers)

Answer (score 1):

On the side note, `std::vector<MyObject*> getVector()` will return a **copy** of that vector, which in terms of OOP principles (encapsulation) is a desirable behaviour:

A call to this getter will not allow to mutate the state of MyClass instance.

Of course perfomance-wise that is poor design, unsless you actually need to return a copy (rather strange specification for a getter). That is why you should return a *reference to const object*, which in the same time allows returning the object itself (no copying) while disallowing its mutation.

Comment: OP said that they do not want to allow objects pointed to by the pointers to be modified ;  which that call does allow (and so would your suggestion)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether it's correct or not. I just use

```
class MyClass {
  std::vector<MyObject*> my_objects_;
 public:
  const std::vector<const MyObject*> &getVector() {
    return *reinterpret_cast<const std::vector<const MyObject *> *>(&my_objects_);
  }
};
```

to do the trick.